# xcb: LeaveNotify received immediately after EnterNotify

Tags: rust, x11, window-managers, xcb

I am in the process of writing a window manager in Rust for learning purposes, using the [xcb](https://crates.io/crates/xcb) library. My code and several test windows (`xterm` instances) are all running inside of a Xephyr session. I set my event mask on the root window as

```
xproto::EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_POINTER_MOTION
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_LEAVE_WINDOW
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_ENTER_WINDOW
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_FOCUS_CHANGE
```

and all child windows have an event mask of

```
xproto::EVENT_MASK_ENTER_WINDOW
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_LEAVE_WINDOW
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_POINTER_MOTION
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_FOCUS_CHANGE
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY
| xproto::EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE
```

When I move the mouse over a non-root window, I use the `EnterNotify` event to grab mouse buttons on that window, for click-to-focus purposes, and ungrab on `LeaveNotify`. The sequence of events is:

- Mouse on root window
- Move mouse over non-root window
- Receive `EnterNotify` for non-root window
- Grab buttons on the non-root window
- Immediately receive `LeaveNotify`, *while the mouse is still over the non-root window*
- Ungrab buttons due to `LeaveNotify`
- Attempt clicking on the non-root window
- Receive a second `LeaveNotify` for the non-root window
- Receive an `EnterNotify` for the root window, and grab mouse buttons on the root window
- `ButtonPress` is sent for the root window, despite the cursor being over a non-root window

I'm genuinely unsure what the cause of this might be; using Google and the like has turned up nothing useful.

---

For anyone who might stumble across this later, a partial solution is:

- Only listen on window enter events to grab buttons on a window
- Mask root to be `SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT | SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY | BUTTON_PRESS` only
- Don't mask `LEAVE_WINDOW` onto non-root windows, and don't handle those events

I don't want to add this as an answer because:

1. I'm unsure it's the correct way of doing it.
2. I've not tested this thoroughly.
3. It doesn't answer my primary question of "why are events received like this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the protocol reference manual. It describes (among lots of other things) the exact algorithm for generating enter and leave events: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#events:pointer_window

In your specific case, I would expect the `LeaveNotify` event to have `mode: Grab`, which means that the window no longer has the "normal" pointer focus, because something (your program) grabbed the input.

If this is not the answer, I can recommend running your WM under [xtrace / x11trace](https://www.openhub.net/p/x11trace) (available in Debian-based distros as package `xtrace`). This program prints all X11 traffic that "goes through". This might help figuring out what is going on.

Comment: That appears to be it! Thank you so much!